# iOS: Auto-layout constraints acting strange when designing TableView for iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ipad, ios-autolayout

I am trying to have simple custom table view cells with `UIImageView` and another `View` with three `Labels` in it.

I set the constrains to 5 from `UIImageView` and 0 from all remaining sizes. But as soon as I select bigger iPad in the Xcode designer (like iPad Pro or Pro with 12,9" screen) I suddenly get space on the right side even though the constraints still says "0" when clicked.

The screenshot below should help illustrate the issue (first is regular iPad, then iPad Pro 10.5" and finally iPad Pro 12,9"):

[image: Auto-layout issues on different iPad sizes]

I already did some auto-layout work for iPhone and never encountered something like this.

Comment: do you get any error when you change device?

Comment: @rv7284 no nothing. Not even warnings in scene designer about constraints..

Comment: if you resize cell will it adjust is self